# RSA Private Key set as environment variable on AWS Lambda configuration returns error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rsa

I have an RSA private key set as an environment variable in AWS Lambda (set through the console).

After setting the cfSigner variable:

```
  const cfSigner = new aws.CloudFront.Signer(
    process.env.CLOUDFRONT_PUB_KEY_ID,
    process.env.CLOUDFRONT_PRIVATE_KEY
  );
```

Running the `getSignedUrl` method on cfSigner returns the following error:

```
PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

But when logged in to the console, the key exists.

So I tried using a .env file in my serverless folder instead, and, curiously enough, it solved the issue. But I always try to avoid storing secrets in the .env file and I'd rather store them in the AWS lambda configuration directly in the "Environment variables" section.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You say "this returns the following error". *What* returns the following error? Did you print the value of the environment variable in the Lambda function? Is it what you expected it to be?

Comment: Your key should starts with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- (5 dashes)